# How does bash handle control characters?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tty, control-characters

I'm writing a shell that tries to simulate bash's behaviour. The problem is that I've read that when Bash gets the user input, it uses a non-canonical mode and turn off the ECHO kind of like this :

```
(*conf)->newterm.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
```

But if it turns ECHO off, how is SIGINT still displayed as `^C` on the temrinal ? When I try this, I get the character `�` which is `-1` (if you try to print it).

If we pay enough attention to bash behaviour, control characters are never displayed except for ctrl-c AKA *SIGINT*. My only theory is that bash hard coded `^C` and just print it to the screen when *SIGINT* is detected. Am I right saying this ? Of not, how does BASH or ZSH  display `^C` having `ECHO` and `ICANON` turned off ? I've looked everywhere and I really can't seem to find an answer to this...

Thank you for your time and your explanation !

EDIT :
Here is what I do. First I initialize my shell as this :

```
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &(*conf)->oldterm);
(*conf)->newterm = (*conf)->oldterm;
(*conf)->newterm.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &(*conf)->newterm); // Apply immediately
```

Then well I press ctrl-c, I get a newline and `^C` is not displayed. This is because I'm disabling ECHO so ECHOCTL gets disabled too. Now, What I want to have is if I press `ctr-c`, have `^C` displayed, but also not having `^[[A` when I press the upper arrow key. I'm just unsure how to configure termios to do that.

Comment: Might you provide the context around your `c_lflag` setting (e.g., your calls to `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr`)?

Comment: In output from `stty`, look for `echoctl`.

Comment: @ahi324 I've updated my question and showed how i configure Termios.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `^C` is actually being generated by the terminal device interface (tty), as opposed to Bash or Z Shell.  For example, and following `stty -echoctl` and `stty -echo`, `^C` is no longer displayed.  As another example, a simple C program with `sleep(1)`s in an infinite loop and `SIGINT` set to `SIG_IGN` (and with `stty echo`), still displays `^C`.

This example works for me, the most relevant lines being 17, 19, 20, 36, and 37 (`gcc -Wall` compiled, in macOS and Linux, in Bash and Z Shell, with Terminal [Apple], Terminator, and GNOME Terminal, within and without GNU Screen and/or tmux, and with `TERM`s of `xterm-256color` and `screen-256color`):

```
     1  #include <errno.h>
     2  #include <signal.h>
     3  #include <stdio.h>
     4  #include <termios.h>
     5  #include <unistd.h>
     6  
     7  void sh( int _sig )
     8  {
     9      puts("SIGINT");
    10  }
    11  
    12  int main()
    13  {
    14      struct termios t;
    15      void (*s)(int);
    16  
    17      if ( tcgetattr(fileno(stdin),&t) )
    18          return(1);
    19      t.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    20      if ( tcsetattr(fileno(stdin),TCSANOW,&t) )
    21          return(2);
    22      if ( ( s = signal(SIGINT,&sh) ) == SIG_ERR )
    23          return(3);
    24  
    25      /**
    26       ** While  the  following  `sleep`  is  running,  [ctrl]+c  will
    27       ** trigger a  SIGINT, which will  lead to a  `sh(SIGINT)` call,
    28       ** which  will  lead to  "SIGINT\n"  being  written to  STDOUT,
    29       ** and  `sleep` will  be interrupted,  returning sleep  seconds
    30       ** remaining. "^C" should not be printed to the terminal.
    31       **/
    32      puts("Tap [ctrl]+c within 60 seconds and expect \"SIGINT\"...");
    33      if ( sleep(60) == 0 || errno != EINTR )
    34          return(4);
    35  
    36      t.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    37      if ( tcsetattr(fileno(stdin),TCSANOW,&t) )
    38          return(5);
    39      if ( signal(SIGINT,s) == SIG_ERR )
    40          return(6);
    41  
    42      /**
    43       ** With the default SIGINT handler restored, the following will
    44       ** only return  if the time  fully elapses. And, with  the ECHO
    45       ** bit restored, "^C" should be printed to the terminal (unless
    46       ** such echo'ing was otherwise disabled).
    47       **/
    48      puts("Tap [ctrl]+c within 60 seconds, expect \"^C\", and expect a 130 return (128+SIGINT)...");
    49      sleep(86400);
    50  
    51      return(7);
    52  }
```

*P.S.  Keep in mind that `[ctrl]-c` (generally) triggers a `SIGINT`, that `SIGINT` can be generated without a `[ctrl]-c`, and that, for example, `kill -INT "$pid"`, should not trigger a tty-driven `^C` output.*

Comment: I get it, but if it’s generated by the tty device interface and bash has the ECHO ( and therefore ECHOCTL) disabled, how does the tty able to print ^C ?

Comment: `stty` tells the tty to disable `echo` and/or `echoctl`, not Bash.  With `stty -echo` and/or `stty -echoctl`, `^C` should not be displayed.

Comment: Well I see why this works, *t.c_lflag |= ECHO;* this re-enables ECHO, so ECHOCTL bit is set. But in order to built my shell, I explicitly disable ECHO and the canonical mode. I've also updated my question with of I initialize my shell and what results I expect

Comment: If you're looking for selective echo'ing, perhaps manually echo'ing would be a solution!?  For example, disable `ECHOCTL` and, in your read loop, manually output `^C` when a `[ctrl]+c` sequence is received, etc.!?  Perhaps I'm still missing what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Well that’s what I thought I would do. The thing is that I’m trying to simulate bash behavior as said before. They are two thing that I’ve discovered, first is that when you press ctrl+c, in  bash prompt you get ^C. Second, is that the only control characters that is displayed is ctrl-c and nothing else.  So I looked how bash sets termios and saw that it disables canonical mode as well as ECHO. But disabling ECHO makes so that ^C and other controls characters are not echoed, so that’s why I’m confused, if bash disables ECHO how does ^C  still gets showed on screen

Answer (score 0):

If Bash does use some non standard input mode, it's probably just to support line editing, and not part of its core functionality as a shell. I think a traditional unix shell would just read lines of input, exectute them, and then prompt. An interactive shell would  capture sigint so that the shell wouldn't log you out when you hit ^C, but that's about it. Quite a few things that you might imagine are handled in the shell, are actually not, they're in the kernel, in terminal drivers, input drivers and so forth.

Why are you trying to emulate bash, is this for fun and learning? If you want to do that, you should go start by looking at the source code of older and simpler shells. You could certainly go look at the old bsd "csh" code, or maybe the original bourne shell code. These shells do the essence of what it is to be a shell. There's been even simpler shells if you look for them. Later shells complicate things by adding line editing, and if you want to understand those, you can get the gnu readline library, and add that to your own app. You could add it to your shell for that matter.

Comment: That is purely for fun and gain some experience nothing else ! 
Now, that’s why I set some attributes to the drivers which are disable the canonical mode ( to immediately have data available) and ECHO. But if I disable ECHO, ECHOCTL is also disabled and therefore ^C is never displayed on SIGINT. According to termios : «ECHOCTL : (not in POSIX) If ECHO is also set, terminal special characters other than TAB, NL, START, and STOP are echoed as ^X, where X is the character with ASCII code 0x40 greater than the special character »